# Python subclass definitions

Tags: python, oop

I am currently attempting a personal project to improve my oop ability.  I am having trouble creating a good class structure for a damage modeling program, based on a game that I play.

Specifically I feel like I am hard coding too many aspects of my subclasses.  I have simplified the problem to the following.  I have a superclass called gun which contains the basic elements of any gun in the game.

```
class gun():

def __init__(self,critc,maxa):
    self.critc = critc
    self.maxa = maxa
    self.currentmag = maxa

def shoot(self):
    self.currentmag -= 1
```

Now I want to create a specific gun class without actually instantiating it.  My reasoning behind this is if there is 100 types of guns not all gun subclasses need to be instantiated at one time. However, all of my gun subclass definitions end up looking very similar with only slight changes for specific values.  Is there a common/simple way to clean this up?

```
class gun1(gun):
    def __init__(self):
      self.critc = 10
      self.maxa = 20

class gun2(gun):
    def __init__(self):
      self.critc = 11
      self.maxa = 25
```

I would like to find something similar to:

```
class gun1(gun(10,11))
```

Which is not actually usable, but well encapsulates what I would like.  That is, having the definitions of each subclass be short, concise, and not redundant.  In the above example 10 is the critc variable and 11 is the maxa variable.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If all of your class definitions would be very similar, why don't you use one class with some keyword arguments. For example, you could keep your class `gun` and create different instances with `gun(critc=10, maxa=10)`. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

On the lines of what Jakub has already stated, you could just copy the `class` around and change it's attributes without instantiation.

```
>>> class Gun():
...     critc = 0
...     maxa = 0
...     def __init__(self, critc=None, maxa=None):
...         if critc:
...             self.critc = critc
...         if maxa:
...             self.maxa = maxa
...         self.currentmag = maxa
...     def shoot(self):
...         self.currentmag -= 1
... 
>>> Kalashnikov = Gun
>>> Kalashnikov.critc = 15
>>> Kalashnikov.maxa = 40
>>> k = Kalashnikov(15, 40)
>>> k
<__main__.Gun instance at 0x7fcc0f482200>
>>> k.shoot()
>>> k.maxa
40
>>> k.currentmag
39
>>> AK47 = Gun
>>> AK47.critc = 30
>>> AK47.maxa = 30
>>> a = AK47()
>>> a.critc
30
```